# Symfony2 Doctrine DBAL Wrapper Issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dbal

I am trying to create a custom wrapper for a DBAL connection and have correctly setup the config.yml file,

however I am getting the following error:

```
DBALException: The given 'wrapperClass' Some\Bundle\Doctrine\DBAL\ExtendedConnection 
has to be a subtype of \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.
```

However my class is extending the `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`:

```
namespace Some\Bundle\Doctrine\DBAL\ExtendedConnection;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection AS Connection;

class ExtendedConnection extends Connection
{
    public function multipleResultSetsFetchAll()
    {
        $stmt = $this->getConnection();
        do{
            $results[] = $stmt->fetchAll();
        }while($stmt->nextRowset());

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the problem here - it was the filename. My file name was Conection.php but changing it to ExtendedConnection.php worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to note that when defining the class name in your doctrine yaml or xml, you must supply the fully qualified namespace. This was a gotcha for me as doctrines documentation only uses the class name. Good ole doctrine!